# hostapd compile error

Tags: wireless, 13.04, compiling

while trying to build hostapt I get the following error.

```
make
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:17:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../src/crypto/tls_openssl.o] Error 1
```

I am trying to create a infrastructure mode hotspot with Ubuntu 13.04 without using router, mainly for my android phone.

I am using this [guide](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd).

Comment: Install `libnl1`, `sudo apt-get install libnl1` as described by the guide you're following.

Comment: done that, but the error still shows.

Comment: done that too. same error,

Comment: Ok! Try installing one of these packages: `libssl-dev` or `python-pyopenssl`.

Comment: ok. now its this

:~/hostap/hostapd$ make  CC  ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/crypto_openssl.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hostapd] Error 1

Answer (score 5):

This solution came from the comments of the above post. (The reason I am writing a solution instead of a comment is I do not have the reputation currently to write a comment and I wanted to let people know that this worked for me).

I installed libssl-dev using:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then I ran

```
make clean
```

Then

```
make
```

After this it worked for me.
Thank you to above commenters for clearing that up.